# ANY or IF EXISTS in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which is a mapping between foreign ids and local ids.

I had to write a query to find out whether or not this table is a bijection.  I came up with this

```
IF 1 <> ANY(
    SELECT COUNT(foreignId)
    FROM mappingTable
    GROUP BY localId
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Oh noes!'
END

ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT 'Everything is fine.'
END
```

My supervisor took one look at this and grimaced, and told me I should have written this instead:

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM mappingTable
    GROUP BY localId
    HAVING COUNT(foreignId) <> 1
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Oh noes!'
END

ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT 'Everything is fine.'
END
```

My question is simply which of these queries is better style.  I'm pretty sure that they are equivalent.

Comment: Why not use a UNIQUE constraint on the table? Like UNIQUE(localId, foreignId) so that each mapping can be only insereted once. The check is done by the database engine and you don't have to write any code.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly I'm trying to check the sanity of data received from external sources.

Comment: Then create the table and the constraint first and try inserting the data afterwards. Your DB system should throw an error if the data is not correct. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Testing on SQL Server 2008 shows that these queries not only give identical results, they even have identical query plans. The query optimiser already knows that these queries are equivalent. You're right, therefore, that any argument favouring one over the other will have to focus on other aspects such as style.

For me personally, the second query is easier to understand, even though the first query more closely follows how you would express the search in English, because I've seen `EXISTS` far more than `ANY`. The first query makes me go "wait, what? Oh yeah, that's right..." The second is immediately obvious to me. It can be different for others (perhaps for you); you should try to make sure your queries are as easy to read for your supervisor and colleagues.

Answer (score 3):

Your queries are equally bad or equally good depending on if you have a index on your column or not.

With no index there will be a Table Scan/ Clustered Index Scan of all rows followed by a Hash Match that removes the duplicates.

If you have an index on the column you are checking, both queries will use that index and terminate early when a duplicate is found.

Query plan with index:

[image]

Query plan without index:

[image]